# Ubuntu 16.04 Cinnamon DE battery applet broken

Tags: battery, cinnamon, applet

Has anyone noticed that the default battery applet in the cinnamon DE from the default Xenial repo will not consistently tell a correct percentage or time remaining? Anyone found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

i guess i found an trick...
download another applet called battery monitor.
this applet is a little ugly (green background)
then after, insert a pen drive and wait until shows a new nautilus window.
go to computer, select view hidden files and search applet (all files)
find battery monitor folder and select and open with gedit stylesheet.css
the solution is removing background color line... save the file and reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still present.
The problem is releated to a bug present on the repository about cinnamon-session-manager that doesn't send all change signals to applets, so the battery applet isn't notified when the percentage change.

You can see the right battery percentage from terminal with the command

```
upower -d
```

or you can update the percentage on the power applet by plug the AC adapter and unplug it.

Clearly these are not the best solutions to keep under control the battery so I write an hack to make the cinnamon applet work until you will update your distro to the next LTS where the problem will be already solved.

Change the content of the file:

```
/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/power@cinnamon.org/applet.js
```

with the content you I put [here](https://pastebin.com/ik0TSRnA):

What I did it's simply to create a polling that force to update the power applet informations every 90 seconds.